# using joins to find users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am building an inbox section in my app. The conversations are only ever between two parties, actors and clients.

On the inbox page I am finding all 'Conversations' documents where the clientId $or actorId field matches that of Meteor.userId()

So the cursor returns the documents matching this criteria which is as expected. Let's say I'm logged in as an actor and I've had conversations with 5 different clients, these 5 conversation documents would be sent to the client.

How can I then get the 5 different clientId's of those conversation docs and and create a subscription to return only those user objects?

The reason I want to do this is to display the users profile picture, name and provide a link through the their profile page.

Here's my code:

**Publication**

```
    Meteor.publish('Conversations', function() {
  return Conversations.find({$or: [{'clientId': this.userId}, {'actorId': this.userId}]});
});
```

**Route/Subscription**

```
// Inbox
  Router.route('/inbox', {
    name: 'inbox',
    waitOn: function() {
      return [Meteor.subscribe('Messages', this.params._id), Meteor.subscribe('Conversations')]
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested these techniques but I believe you are looking at one of these.

1. using [$lookup aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) (this make a songle collection based on 2)
2. db.small_collection.find().forEach(function(obj){ 
   db.big_collection.find(obj)
   });